# Transform odbc connection strings to SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, connection-string, sqlclient

We've got various apps that connect to Sql server, some using odbc, and others via  SqlClient, therefore leading to strings in both formats (!).

I'm trying to consolidate the strings, so is there a standard way I can store them in odbc and transform them into SqlClient for those apps that need them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've created a (currently) quick and dirty function below which uses the ConnectionStringBuilder, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way of doing this... (?) This seems somewhat smelly.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a SQLClient Connection String from an ODBC string 
    /// </summary>
    private string ODBCToSqlClient(string ODBCConnectionString)
    {           
        OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder(ODBCConnectionString);                        
        if (builder.ContainsKey("Uid"))            
        {
            //Standard Connection
            return string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};User Id={2};Password={3};", builder["Server"], builder["Database"], builder["uid"], builder["pwd"]);
        }
        else 
        {
            //Trusted Connection
            return string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Trusted_Connection=True;", builder["Server"], builder["Database"]);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: 3 months after answering with no other answers (and using this for the 3 months), so setting as the answer.